# How to get all sorted permutations of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

Given a list, I want all the permutations of a certain length, but only those that remain sorted.

So if the list is

```
[1,1,3,4]
```

then the answer with length 2 is

```
 [[1,1], [1,1], [1,3], [1,3] [3,4], [1,4], [1,4]]
```

Please provide an efficient answer.

Comment: Why do you have `[1,3]` twice but `[1,1]` just once? How do you want to treat duplicates?

Comment: So you do not want to remove the duplicates? Then the answer by @Inbar is perfectly fine. Just do `sorted(r)` instead of casting to `set` first.

Answer (score 7):

```
import itertools

l = [1, 1, 3, 4]
r = [perm for perm in itertools.permutations(l, 2) if sorted(perm) == list(perm)]
```

results in:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4)]
```

If you want the results sorted, and unique:

```
s = sorted(set(r))  #  [(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4)]
```

If you want the results as lists instead of tuples, just cast them as `list()`

---

Using the recipe for [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) I made this convenience function for you:

```
def sorted_perms(iterable, r=None):
    pool = tuple(sorted(iterable))
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    for indices in itertools.product(range(n), repeat=r):
        if len(set(indices)) == r and tuple_is_sorted(indices):
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

memo = {}  # simple memoization for efficiency.
def tuple_is_sorted(t):
    return memo.setdefault(t, bool(sorted(t) == list(t)))

r = list(sorted_perms(l, 2))  #  [(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4)]
s = sorted(set(r))  #  [(1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: Will Python then actually calculate all the permutations first and then remove all unsorted ones? Isn't that kind of inefficient?

Comment: @ImeanH It will, yes and theoretically it is inefficient but what other good options do you have?

Comment: @ImeanH In the answer I gave yes, that is what it will do, that was the question in the OP .

Comment: @InbarRose It was a poor answer then.

Comment: @ImeanH This is a better option to the `None` option you have.

Comment: @ImeanH Gave you a better method.

Comment: @ImeanH No need for hostility, i'm not in it for the rep. And In case you missed it I did provide another solution which I think is more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and `operator.le` to filter

```
import itertools
import operator

l = [1, 1, 3, 4]

unique = filter(lambda x: operator.le(x[0], x[1]), itertools.permutations(l, 2))

print(sorted(unique))
```

Output

```
[(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Transform it to lists

```
print([[a, b] for a, b in sorted(unique)])
```

Output

```
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

itertools.permutation is very slow function for you.

```
>>> a = [5, 3,4,1]
>>> b = sorted(range(len(a)), key = lambda i: a[i])
>>> perm = [ (a[i], b[i]) for i in range(len(b))]
>>> perm
[(3, 5), (1, 3), (2, 4), (0, 1)]
```